# XML Issues- Loads a Blank Page

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I am new to XML coding and I am working on a site right now to help me improve on the skill. I think i got all the syntax right for the page but it seems not to be working. Here's the code for the index page and also the xml file I am trying to make use of.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var link= "http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(55423,10))+products(name=playstation*)?show=storeId,name,products.sku,products.name&page=1&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>"); 
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("Step 2");
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("distance")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the XML i got off a sample best buy request

```
<stores warnings="Distances are in terms of miles (default). Your product criteria matches too many records. That exceeds number of records that we allow on the product side of a store-product query. We've automatically truncated the products down to the first 100. These results are not complete. Avoid this by narrowing the number of products in your query." currentPage="1" totalPages="1" from="1" to="10" total="10" queryTime="0.015" totalTime="0.153" canonicalUrl="/v1/stores(area("55423",10))+products(name="playstation*")?show=storeId,name,products.sku,products.name&apiKey=ydpyq9h9cmpmzaakbawv9mzk" partial="false">
  <store>
    <storeId>281</storeId>
    <name>Richfield</name>
    <products>
      <product>
        <sku>9984133</sku>
        <name>Assassin's Creed Brotherhood - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>7917141</sku>
        <name>Assassin's Creed Greatest Hits - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>2613621</sku>
        <name>Assassin's Creed: Revelations - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>3109269</sku>
        <name>Assassin's Creed: Revelations Collector's Edition (Game Guide) - Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Windows</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>3109065</sku>
        <name>Assassin's Creed: Revelations The Complete Official Guide (Game Guide) - Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Windows</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>9927337</sku>
        <name>Batman: Arkham Asylum Game of the Year Edition - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>3116162</sku>
        <name>Batman: Arkham City (Signature Series Game Guide) - Windows, PlayStation 3, Xbox 360</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>5260722</sku>
        <name>Batman: Arkham City - Game of the Year Edition - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>2173056</sku>
        <name>Batman: Arkham City - PlayStation 3</name>
      </product>
      <product>
        <sku>3550073</sku>
        <name>Battlefield 3 (Game Guide) - Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Windows</name>
      </product>
</products>
  </store>
</stores>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put the code that executes after the data is loaded in the `onreadystatechange` event of the `xmlhttp` object: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httprequest.readyState == 4) {
        // Response finished
        if (httprequest.status = 200) {
           // everything OK
           // Parse the data
        } else {
           // Something gone wrong with the request
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Looking at your code now I realized that you are using `var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");`. This will select EVERY tag `name`, including the inner one. Try using `store` to get each one instead of the name and then look for `product`.

Also, you are using a hard coded limit in the for loop. Use `x.length` instead: `for (var i=0; i<x.length;i++)`

Comment: This is the error I am getting when when i debug via chrome
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null"

Comment: Have you made the change I've said?

Comment: I tried to but not sure if i am doing the right thing. I do I put the rest of the code in the status 200 condition? It'll help if you post the edited code if you can please.

Comment: Yes, put all the code you have below the `xmlhttp.send();` line inside the status 200 condition.

Comment: I just did now but the same result. Here's my syntax...
http://jsfiddle.net/5pMtn/

Comment: I've added some more tips to the answer.